# Cufon causing an delay in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, internet-explorer, cufon

I'm using an externally rendered control to create an menu on a webpage. The control is coming from an cms system and can't be modified. When calling Cufon.replace() to change the font of the menu items provided we notice an flickering effect in IE8, like there is some sort of delay. In FireFox 4 and Chrome this effect isn't visible. I've read other topics on stackoverflow about it, but none seem to look similar to this problem. It only occurs on hovering over the menu item.

We're familiar with the fact the Cufon needs to be called straight after the html-element of which the font needs to be changed. Is this still necessary? Or do I need to call a Cufon.Now() somewhere? What is causing the flickering effect here when I hover about the menu-items?

```
<cc1:MenuBuilder ID="Mainmenu" MenuName="Mainmenu" runat="server" CssClass="menubar-nav-list" UseDiv="true" ShowLevels="1" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('#Mainmenu .menuitem', { fontFamily: 'DIN Eng', hover: true });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the following code right after the `<body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script>
```

And then call

```
Cufon.replace('#Mainmenu .menuitem', { fontFamily: 'DIN Eng', hover: true });
```

or simply

```
Cufon('#Mainmenu .menuitem', { fontFamily: 'DIN Eng', hover: true });
```

The Cufon.now is doing the trick. For more information read the [documentation](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API). In this documentation they say to use it before the `</body>` but we found that this doesn't fix all the flickering problems but right after the `<body>` does.

Comment: Indeed solved the flickering problems! Good solution, thnx ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, so this is just a shot in the dark.

To use DOM selection methods like #Mainmenu .menuitem (instead of just h1 or h2), Cufon requires a javascript library like jQuery.

Is it possible that jQuery isn't loading at the right time, or that you've set IE to no-cache mode, forcing it to redownload jQuery every time you reload the page?

Comment: jQuery is loaded, i'm sure about that. But maybe not before cufon, so will check that out. Could it be loaded at the wrong moment? Good tip about the caching too, never thought about that. Will check this and get back to you.

Comment: I checked the website this morning. jQuery is loaded before cufon is, so we're sure about that. Also the caching seems to be normal. Any other ideas?